# Parallel FOR loop with OpenACC using recursive pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, parallel-processing, openacc

I have this parallel FOR loop with OpenMP:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(k,cell) shared(sim,mesh)
    for(i=0;i<mesh->ncells;i++){
        cell=&(mesh->cell[i]);
        for(k=0;k<sim->nvar;k++){
            cell->U_aux[k]=cell->U[k];
            cell->U[k]-=sim->dt*((cell->w2->fL_star[k]-cell->w4->fR_star[k])/cell->dx + (cell->w3->fL_star[k]-cell->w1->fR_star[k])/cell->dy + (cell->w6->fL_star[k]-cell->w5->fR_star[k])/cell->dz);
        }            
    }
}
```

with `cell` a pointer to an array of cells in the estructure `mesh`. and I would like to parallelize it with OpenACC.

The structure `sim` only includes scalars, but the structures `mesh` includes 1D arrays of `cell` and `wall`

```c
struct t_mesh_{
    int ncells;
    t_cell *cell;
    t_wall *wall;
    // and other variables not used in this function...
};
```

where the structure `cell` is defined as:

```c
struct t_cell_{
    double dx,dy,dz;
    double *U,*U_aux;
    t_wall *w1, *w2, *w3, *w4, *w5, *w6;
    // and other variables not used in this function...
};
```

Note that `*U,*U_aux` are small 1D arrays but `*w1, *w2, *w3, *w4, *w5, *w6` are **pointers** to the array `wall`:

```c
struct t_wall_{
    double *fR_star,*fL_star;
    // and other variables not used in this function...
};
```

where `fR_star` and `fL_star` are small 1D arrays.

¿How should I define the OpenACC pragma and manage the memory?

Thanks in advance.

**[Edited]**

In the script attached below, the creation and allocation of the structures, as well as the pointers used in the loop of interest is shown. Most parts of the code have been omitted, only retaining those mentioned in the question:

```c
//macros omitted

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////  S T R U C T U R E S  ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct t_node_ t_node;
typedef struct t_cell_ t_cell; 
typedef struct t_wall_ t_wall;
typedef struct t_mesh_ t_mesh;
typedef struct t_sim_ t_sim;

struct t_node_{
    int id;
    double x,y; 

};

struct t_cell_{
    int id;
    int l,m;
    double *U;  //array of cell-valued variables
    double dx,dy;
    double xc,yc;
    int n1,n2,n3,n4; 
    int w1_id,w2_id,w3_id,w4_id;
    t_wall *w1, *w2, *w3, *w4; //pointers to mesh->wall 
};

struct t_wall_{
    int id;
    double *fR_star,*fL_star; //array of left and right fluxes at each wall (same dimension than U)
    int cellR_id, cellL_id; 
    t_cell *cellR, *cellL; //pointers to the right and left cells of the wall (mesh->cell)
    double nx, ny;

};

struct t_mesh_{
    int xcells, ycells; 
      double dx, dy;
    int ncells; //number of cells
    int nwalls; //number of walls
    int nnodes;
    t_cell *cell; //array of cell structures
    t_wall *wall; //array of wall structures
    t_node *node; //array of node structures
    t_sim *sim;
};

struct t_sim_{
    double dt,t,CFL; 
    double tf, tVolc; 
    int rk_steps; 
    int order; 
    int nvar; //number of variables (dimension of U, fR_star, fL_star...)

};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////  F U N C T I O N   D E F I N I T I O N //////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int create_mesh(t_mesh *mesh,t_sim *sim);
void update_cellK1(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////  P R E - P R O C.   F U N C T I O N S ///////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int create_mesh(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim){
    int i,l,m,k,aux,p;
    int xcells,ycells; 
    t_cell *cell;
    t_wall *wall;
    t_node *node;
    int semiSt;
    

    mesh->sim=sim;

    //Cells
    xcells=mesh->xcells;
    ycells=mesh->ycells;
    mesh->ncells=xcells*ycells;
    mesh->cell=(t_cell*)malloc(mesh->ncells*sizeof(t_cell));
    cell=mesh->cell;    
      
    //Walls
    mesh->nwalls=2*mesh->ncells+xcells+mesh->ycells;
    mesh->wall=(t_wall*)malloc(mesh->nwalls*sizeof(t_wall));

    wall=mesh->wall;
    for(k=0;k<mesh->nwalls;k++){
        wall[k].id=k;
        wall[k].fR_star=(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
        wall[k].fL_star=(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
    }

    //Walls and nodes of the cells
    for(m=0;m<ycells-1;m++){
        for(l=0;l<xcells-1;l++){
            
            k=xcells*m+l;
            cell[k].id=k;
            cell[k].l=l;
            cell[k].m=m;
            
            cell[k].w1_id=2*(k)+m;
            // ...

            cell[k].w1=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w1_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall 
            cell[k].w2=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w2_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall 
            cell[k].w3=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w3_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall 
            cell[k].w4=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w4_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall 
                  // ...
                    // ...

        }
    }

    //Assigment of wall's neighbour cells 
    for(m=0;m<ycells;m++){
        for(l=0;l<xcells;l++){
            
            k=xcells*m+l;
            cell[k].w1->cellR_id=cell[k].id;
                  // ...

            cell[k].w1->cellR=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w4->cellR=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w2->cellL=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w3->cellL=&(cell[k]);

            //...
                  //other special cases omitted
                  //...

        }
    }

    //Allocation of arrays of variables "U" in cells and walls
    for(k=0;k<mesh->ncells;k++){        
        mesh->cell[k].U    =(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
    }
    
    return 1;
}


void update_cellK1(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim){   
    int i,k;
    t_cell *cell;  
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(k,cell) shared(sim,mesh)
    for(i=0;i<mesh->ncells;i++){
        cell=&(mesh->cell[i]);
        for(k=0;k<sim->nvar;k++){
            cell->U[k]-=sim->dt*((cell->w2->fL_star[k]-cell->w4->fR_star[k])/cell->dx + (cell->w3->fL_star[k]-cell->w1->fR_star[k])/cell->dy);
        }
    }   
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// M A I N ///////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    
    int i, j, k, p;
    t_mesh *mesh;
    t_sim *sim;
    double tf,t;
    int nIt; 
    double timeac; 
      
    omp_set_num_threads(NTHREADS);     

    //Mesh and sim allocation
    mesh=(t_mesh*)malloc(sizeof(t_mesh));
    sim =(t_sim*)malloc(sizeof(t_sim));
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////// P R E - P R O C E S S ///////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //...
    //variable initialization and file reading omitted
    //cell->dx= ...
    //cell->dy= ...
    //...
      
    create_mesh(mesh,sim); 
    update_initial(mesh); //this function (omitted) assings the initial values of cell[k].U[0] ... cell[k].U[4]

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////// C A L C U L A T I O N ///////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    tf=sim->tf;
    sim->t=0.0;
    t=0.0;
    while(t<tf){        
        compute_fluxes(mesh,sim); //this function (omitted) computes *fR_star,*fL_star of walls (line 32), which are then used in "update_cellK1()"
        update_dt(mesh,sim);      //this function (omitted) computes sim->dt
        update_cellK1(mesh,sim);                                
        t+=sim->dt; //Time updated
        sim->t=t;          
    }
    
    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to compile with CUDA Unified Memory assuming you're using either the PGI Compiler (-ta=tesla:managed) or NVIDIA HPC Compiler (-acc -gpu=managed).  Provided that the memory is allocated, the CUDA runtime will handle all the data management for you.

Though if you do need to manually manage the data, while tricky for this case, it's not too difficult.  If you can provide an example code which show how you create the full structures, I can help show you how to manage the data.  Most likely we'll want to use the OpenACC API calls so we can directly manage the device pointers and use either "acc_attach" or "acc_map_data" calls to have the "w" variables point to the correct "wall".

[EDIT]

Below is my first attempt at adding manual data movement.  I opted for the easier route of using directives and then attaching the already allocated device data.  The problem being that since the code is incomplete (would have been good to have dummy values for initialization), I can't actually test if the code works as expected.  Sometimes in these types of codes, we need to opt to use only the API calls so we can have direct control over the pointers.

```
//macros omitted
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _OPENACC
#include <openacc.h>
#endif

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////  S T R U C T U R E S  ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct t_node_ t_node;
typedef struct t_cell_ t_cell;
typedef struct t_wall_ t_wall;
typedef struct t_mesh_ t_mesh;
typedef struct t_sim_ t_sim;

struct t_node_{
    int id;
    double x,y;

};

struct t_cell_{
    int id;
    int l,m;
    double *U;  //array of cell-valued variables
    double dx,dy;
    double xc,yc;
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    int w1_id,w2_id,w3_id,w4_id;
    t_wall *w1, *w2, *w3, *w4; //pointers to mesh->wall
};

struct t_wall_{
    int id;
    double *fR_star,*fL_star; //array of left and right fluxes at each wall (same dimension than U)
    int cellR_id, cellL_id;
    t_cell *cellR, *cellL; //pointers to the right and left cells of the wall (mesh->cell)
    double nx, ny;

};

struct t_mesh_{
    int xcells, ycells;
      double dx, dy;
    int ncells; //number of cells
    int nwalls; //number of walls
    int nnodes;
    t_cell *cell; //array of cell structures
    t_wall *wall; //array of wall structures
    t_node *node; //array of node structures
    t_sim *sim;
};

struct t_sim_{
    double dt,t,CFL;
    double tf, tVolc;
    int rk_steps;
    int order;
    int nvar; //number of variables (dimension of U, fR_star, fL_star...)

};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////  F U N C T I O N   D E F I N I T I O N //////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int create_mesh(t_mesh *mesh,t_sim *sim);
void update_cellK1(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////  P R E - P R O C.   F U N C T I O N S ///////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int create_mesh(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim){
    int i,l,m,k,aux,p;
    int xcells,ycells;
    t_cell *cell;
    t_wall *wall;
    t_node *node;
    int semiSt;

    mesh->sim=sim;

    //Cells
    xcells=mesh->xcells;
    ycells=mesh->ycells;
    mesh->ncells=xcells*ycells;
    mesh->cell=(t_cell*)malloc(mesh->ncells*sizeof(t_cell));
    cell=mesh->cell;

    //Walls
    mesh->nwalls=2*mesh->ncells+xcells+mesh->ycells;
    mesh->wall=(t_wall*)malloc(mesh->nwalls*sizeof(t_wall));

#ifdef _OPENACC
    acc_attach((void**)&mesh->sim);
#pragma acc update device(mesh->ncells,mesh->nwalls)
#pragma acc enter data create(mesh->cell[:mesh->ncells],mesh->wall[:mesh->nwalls])
#endif

    wall=mesh->wall;
    for(k=0;k<mesh->nwalls;k++){
        wall[k].id=k;
        wall[k].fR_star=(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
        wall[k].fL_star=(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
#pragma acc enter data create(wall[k].fR_star[:sim->nvar], wall[k].fL_star[:sim->nvar])
    }

    //Walls and nodes of the cells
    for(m=0;m<ycells-1;m++){
        for(l=0;l<xcells-1;l++){

            k=xcells*m+l;
            cell[k].id=k;
            cell[k].l=l;
            cell[k].m=m;

            cell[k].w1_id=2*(k)+m;
            // ...

            cell[k].w1=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w1_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall
            cell[k].w2=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w2_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall
            cell[k].w3=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w3_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall
            cell[k].w4=&(mesh->wall[cell[k].w4_id]);  // <------- cells' walls used in function "update_cellK1()" are pointers to mesh->wall
                  // ...
                    // ...
#ifdef _OPENACC
#pragma acc update device(cell[k:1])
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w1);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w2);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w3);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w4);
#endif
        }
    }

    //Assigment of wall's neighbour cells
    for(m=0;m<ycells;m++){
        for(l=0;l<xcells;l++){

            k=xcells*m+l;
            cell[k].w1->cellR_id=cell[k].id;
                  // ...

            cell[k].w1->cellR=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w4->cellR=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w2->cellL=&(cell[k]);
            cell[k].w3->cellL=&(cell[k]);

            //...
                  //other special cases omitted
                  //...
#ifdef _OPENACC
#pragma acc update device(cell[k].w1->cellR_id)
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w1->cellR);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w4->cellR);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w2->cellL);
            acc_attach((void**)&cell[k].w3->cellL);
#endif

        }
    }

    //Allocation of arrays of variables "U" in cells and walls
    for(k=0;k<mesh->ncells;k++){
        mesh->cell[k].U    =(double*)malloc(sim->nvar*sizeof(double));
#pragma acc enter data create(mesh->cell[k].U[:sim->nvar])
    }

    return 1;
}


void update_cellK1(t_mesh *mesh, t_sim *sim){
    int i,k;
    t_cell *cell;
#pragma acc parallel loop present(mesh,sim) private(cell)
    for(i=0;i<mesh->ncells;i++){
        cell=&(mesh->cell[i]);
        for(k=0;k<sim->nvar;k++){
            cell->U[k]-=sim->dt*((cell->w2->fL_star[k]-cell->w4->fR_star[k])/cell->dx + (cell->w3->fL_star[k]-cell->w1->fR_star[k])/cell->dy);
        }
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// M A I N ///////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int i, j, k, p;
    t_mesh *mesh;
    t_sim *sim;
    double tf,t;
    int nIt;
    double timeac;

    //Mesh and sim allocation
    mesh=(t_mesh*)malloc(sizeof(t_mesh));
    sim =(t_sim*)malloc(sizeof(t_sim));


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////// P R E - P R O C E S S ///////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //...
    //variable initialization and file reading omitted
    //cell->dx= ...
    //cell->dy= ...
    //...
#pragma acc enter data copyin(mesh[:1]) create(sim[:1])

    create_mesh(mesh,sim);
//    update_initial(mesh); //this function (omitted) assings the initial values of cell[k].U[0] ... cell[k].U[4]

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////// C A L C U L A T I O N ///////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    tf=sim->tf;
    sim->t=0.0;
    t=0.0;
//    while(t<tf){
//        compute_fluxes(mesh,sim); //this function (omitted) computes *fR_star,*fL_star of walls (line 32), which are then used in "update_cellK1()"
//        update_dt(mesh,sim);      //this function (omitted) computes sim->dt
        update_cellK1(mesh,sim);
//        t+=sim->dt; //Time updated
//        sim->t=t;
//    }

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply and your help. I will prepare a simple version of the code showing how structures and created so that you can give me some advice on how to manage the data.

Comment: I have edited the question above to include the relevant parts of the script where the structures are defined and allocated, and pointers created.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Indeed, the code I provided was incomplete so here it is the link to the complete script: https://github.com/navasmontilla/openacc_test/blob/master/euler.c
I have tried to incorporate the OpenACC directives as you recommended but there might still be something missing...
When compiled using *pgcc*, the compiler says that the loops are not parallelizable due to *complex dependence* of data.

Comment: These are just the inner loops.  The outer loops are getting parallelized and successfully offloaded.  Since the inner loops don't have a "loop" directive, the compiler is attempting to auto-parallelize them.  However since C allows aliasing of pointer of the same type, the compiler must assume that "U" overlaps with one or more of the other pointers so can't prove that the loop is safe to parallelize.  If you want to have the inner loops run in parallel, add a "#pragma acc loop" before the loop to force the compiler to parallelize it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I now understand what is happening. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: When adding #pragma acc loop before the inner loop, the compiler says "CUDA shared memory used for cell", which I would say it is because "cell" is a private variable. However, when running the program an error is returned: "call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution". ¿What is the cause?

Comment: It could be any number of things since it's a generic error.  Basically, a bad address is being accessed.  Though, I tried your code from the link above and it seemed to run correctly (perhaps you fixed it) so don't know why it's occurring.